# Why still providers option available in ngmodule of Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, service

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})
```

As services have already the provide in option for services why still there is providers option in **ngModule**

even if we provide in providers it does same thing right. Or is there anything else that it is usefull

Comment: Sometimes you do not want to have a service available in the root injector.

Comment: root points to app module only right